# Mouse click not working in button added in DOM

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am trying to add this code in my code where i want to have this button in my scene !

```
function performAnnotation(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(event)
    console.log('hello')
}
function loadAnnotationIntoScene() {
    const menuPanel = document.getElementById('menu-panel') as HTMLDivElement
    const _menuList = document.createElement('ul') as HTMLUListElement
    menuPanel.appendChild(_menuList)
    annotation.forEach((element, index) => {
        const myList = document.createElement('li') as HTMLLIElement
        const _list = _menuList.appendChild(myList)
        const myButton = document.createElement('button') as HTMLButtonElement
        myList.appendChild(myButton)
        myButton.classList.add('annotationButton')
        myButton.innerHTML = element['text']
        myButton.addEventListener('click', performAnnotation, false)
    })
}
```

i am trying to create an annotation menu above the scene in right or left hand side but i am not able to add button with event listener !!!

When i try in fiddle it works fine  but in three.js, it doesn't and i believe this is because of the orbit controller that i have in my scene !!

Right now my scene is like this:

[image]

```js
function performAnnotation(event) {
    console.log("hello")
}

const annotation = [1, 2, 3, 4]
function loadAnnotationIntoScene() {
    const menuPanel = document.getElementById('menu-panel')
    const _menuList = document.createElement('ul')
    menuPanel.appendChild(_menuList)
    annotation.forEach((element, index) => {
        const myList = document.createElement('li')
        const _list = _menuList.appendChild(myList)
        const myButton = document.createElement('button')
        myButton.innerHTML = "hello"
        myList.appendChild(myButton)
        myButton.addEventListener('click', performAnnotation, false)
    })
}

loadAnnotationIntoScene()
```

```html
 <div id="menu-panel"></div>
```

can any one suggest me what is the best thing that i can do so that i can have annotation menu in my project !!!

Comment: Show the code you use to add the OrbitControls.

Comment: now i am scared if it not because of controller !!! I am trying everything but no resolve !!
If it is more helpful this is my file, i am sharing this to make sure if it is not because of something else stupid thing :( 
 https://github.com/pravinpoudel/building-annotation/blob/main/src/client/client.ts

Comment: do you think, sharing of the remote url of github will be useful ?